# Convert SQL Query to Hibernate Criteria and Projections

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, subquery, hql, hibernate-criteria

I have query from SQL :

```
select e.* 
from terminal_remote_deployment e
where id = (select top 1 e1.id
            from terminal_remote_deployment e1
            where e1.Terminal_info_id = e.Terminal_info_id
            order by e1.version desc
           );
```

I am trying to write it in HQL like this :

```
final StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder();
            hql.append(" from TerminalRemoteDeployment e");
            hql.append(" where e.id = (Select TOP 1 e1.id from TerminalRemoteDeployment e1 where e1.terminalInfo.id = e.terminalInfo.id order by e1.version desc)");

            Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(hql.toString());
            resultList = (List<TerminalRemoteDeployment>) query.getResultList();
```

I am getting errors with this approach. please help me write criteria in hibernate as I am very new to this.

Comment: You can't use `TOP`, because this is SQL Server exclusive and HQL not support that. The only way is create a exclusive `Query` and use the `setMaxResults` method.

Answer (score 3):

Where clause in inner Subquery of second Append.
It should be **terminal_Info_id** instead of **terminalInfo.id**.

```
final StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder();
        hql.append(" from TerminalRemoteDeployment e");
        hql.append(" where e.id = (Select TOP 1 id from TerminalRemoteDeployment e1 where e1.terminal_Info_id = e.terminal_Info_id order by e1.version desc)");

        Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(hql.toString());
        resultList = (List<TerminalRemoteDeployment>) query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 3):

As already told in comment use [setMaxResult()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setMaxResults(int)) method instead of `TOP` keyword as it's not supported by `HQL`.

Also in the `sub-select` you are using `id` without it's entity alias.

Change it to `Select e1.id from TerminalRemoteDeployment e1`

Answer (score 3):

First of all I am not an expert on Hibernate. But your first query if SQL Server specific:

```
select e.* 
from terminal_remote_deployment e
where id = (select top 1 e1.id
            from terminal_remote_deployment e1
            where e1.Terminal_info_id = e.Terminal_info_id
            order by e1.version desc
           );
```

I would rewrite it using `ROW_NUMBER`(supported by MySQL 8.0/MariaDB/SQL Server/PostgreSQL/Oracle/H2/Derby/...) and then I would use named query:

```
SELECT *
FROM(SELECT e.*,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Terminal_info_id ORDER BY version desc) AS rn
     FROM terminal_remote_deployment e) sub
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: This is not the exact answer to my question but some how the need to write the sub query in hibernate is less with your approach and its helping me to get rid of writing the sub query. I will accept the answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this.

```
select e.* 
from  terminal_remote_deployment e1 JOIN 
      (select e.id, max(e.version)
      from terminal_remote_deployment e group by e.id) as a
on e.id = a.id
```